# Best way to create a table with one column expanding its width, and others minimal based on content

Tags: html, css

What would be the best idea way to have a table (I am not committed to `<table>` if other options are better) where:

- The first column, third and fourth column width is as small as content will allow
- The second column would expand to use all remaining spaced (not used by column 1, 3 and 4) without forcing line returns in the content
- The column width is the same for all the lines in the table

I am trying to replicate what I would get with `display:flex` with `<div>`, where one child could grow, and the other not, but I want each column to have the same width across all rows.

Visual example, table would take full screen width, column width cannot be pre-defined:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   ID    | Title                              | Comments | Votes Count |
| 245325  | Lorem ipsum                        |    5     |      2      |
|   32    | Even longer title                  |    0     |      1      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: any (at least visual) representation to share?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan add visual representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by setting the width of columns 1, 3, and 4 to 1% will force them to shrink to be as small as possible while expanding the second column to fill the remaining space:

```css
td:first-child,
td:nth-child(3n),
td:nth-child(4n) {
  width: 1%;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Comments</td>
    <td>Votes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>245325</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>Even longer title</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```